# Rollup Angular 2 application with dependencies for tree shaking

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rollup, pixi.js

I'm trying here to create angular 2 application build with npm rollup module in order to have a tree shaking that would remove code that is not used within particular application and that all works quite nice when I'm bundling application itself with angular dependencies.

Problem arises as I'm trying to include some external JS libraries, like pixi.js we are using in our project - just as we surely are not using full 100% or what PIXI provides and it would be nice not to ship into prod JS bundle stuff that might not be there.

So what I'm trying to do, according to rollup docs, is to use `rollup-plugin-commonjs` module that would take pixi source, convert it to ES2015 format and then include it into shakable format. But that is not what's happening. All I'm getting are different kind of errors like `pixi.js doesn't export class Texture` and so on.

I have really tried everything I could think of...

Can anyone point me to direction on how to solve this or at least confirm that while pixi devs haven't implemented output for es2015 that is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent article about production release with rollup:

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Comment: That article was a starting point of this. Also it still doesn't cover anything about external, non ES2015 packages to be included in build.